# phaser.js - loading images in loop results in "Key not found in cache"

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to load dynamically created images into my phaser project from a JSON file.
the objects within the array all have the key "name" with a corresponding value of "box"+number

I'm loading them into the preloader like so:

```
var j = 0;
for (i in boxArray){
    game.load.image(boxArray[j].name, 'collCreatorAssets/boxes/'+boxArray[j].name+'.png');
    j++;
}
```

and trying to use them within my code like so:

```
j = 0;
for (i in boxArray){
    var newBox = boxes.create(boxArray[j].xPos, boxArray[j].yPos, boxArray[j].name);
    newBox.body.immovable = true;
    newBox.destructable = boxArray[j].destructable;
    j++;
}
```

logging the array to the console, I get no surprising bad news. the array containing the objects are working fine.

not surprising since the position I get from xPos and yPos respectively check out with the corresponding values within the objects in the array. resulting in properly placed image objects within the game. it's just not loading the images.

the images are also found on the server when loading them in the preload function, the only error I get is when starting the game:

```
Phaser.Cache.getImage: Key "box0" not found in Cache.
```

the parameters of the create function are

```
sprite.create(x,y,'key');
```

and the parameters of the load.image function are

```
game.load.image('key', 'path');
```

I've tested manually loading the images in the preloader and creating the sprites within the game using the loop and it works.

so I can narrow the issue down to the preloader but I don't see what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the issue. I'm an idiot.

the loop was outside the success function of the request to get the JSON file.